# Recursively search and output string from files in a directory hierarchy

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

How can I write a shell script to go through all the sub-directories below a given directory and in each of those sub-directories search the file called "copyright" for strings like "license" or "GPL" and print the lines with those sub-strings. After running this I should  be able to tell what the results were for each copyright file that was found.

Comment: `find` command with `grep` can do but I didn't fully understand the last point.

Comment: If what you want are totals or a sort of summary report try ```awk```, ```wc``` and friends to pull out the information you need.  As I note below this may be a job for ```perl``` and its ```format``` tools ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use find with `-exec`:

```
find . -name copyright -exec grep -H -e "license" -e "GPL" '{}' + >> results
```

Comment: Works great Anubhava. How do I make "license" and "GPL" case insensitive?

Comment: Just use `-i` switch in grep like: `find . -name copyright -exec grep -H -i -e "license" -e "GPL" '{}' + >> results`

Answer (score 1):

## Command

Using `grep` and Bash's `**` (globstar, for deep expansion):

```
shopt -s globstar; # enable ** support
grep -i -E 'licence|GPL' **/copyright
```

### Explanation

- `globstar`:

> If  set,  the  pattern  **  used in a pathname expansion context will
>   match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.   If
>   the  pattern  is followed by a /, only directories and subdirectories
>   match.

- `-E`, `--extended-regexp`:

> Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression (ERE, see below). 
>   (-E is specified by POSIX.)

### References

- [foo OR bar on the same line](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/079#foo_OR_bar_on_the_same_line) with grep ;
- [`globstar` option](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/internals/shell_options#globstar) (in Bash >=4)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the responses. I will try these and let you know.

Comment: The grep works great Edouard but my system does not have globstar.

Comment: `globstar` is available since Bash v4, but off by default. Hence the `shopt -s globstar` at the beginning. Otherwise use the solution given by @anubhava

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sort of embarrassing script I use for producing a "License Report" for a FreeBSD host.  I made it faster by switching out `xargs` for anubhava's `-exec`. Thanks!

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# pkg_license_check
#
# TODO: make this report on unlicensed packages.
#
LICENSES='MIT GPL ART BSD'

for LICENSE in $LICENSES
do

 cd /usr/local/share/licenses
 num=`find . -name LICENSE -exec grep -e "$LICENSE" '{}' + | wc -l`
 echo "Total of $num $LICENSE  Licensed packages as follows:"
 find . -name LICENSE -exec grep -e "$LICENSE" -e '{}' + | awk -F":" '{sub("^\.\/", "", $1); print "\n" $1 "\n" $2 $3}'
 echo -e "\n\n------------------------------------------------------------------------- \n\n"

done
```

A project for one day RSN: rewrite in perl and make "POSIX cross platform" for different packaging systems using plugins. :-)